# Regular expression to check current website location - small issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code to highlight menu item corresponding to current page in my browser:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){

    $("ul#nav a").each(function (){

    var hrefWindow = $(this).attr("href");

    if (hrefWindow == window.location.href.match(/[^/]+$/g)) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    };        
});      
})
```

As you can see expression is looking for string which is just after slash in my web address like:

www.mywebsite.com/thisStringWillBeFoundByExpression ,

everything works fine but there is small issue when I type my domain address for the first time as there will be only www.mywebsite.com (without index.htm after slash) in address bar and my expression won't find a thing.

How to modify my code to add class 'active' to index.htm in case if there is only www.mywebsite.com in the address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `location.pathname` instead of parsing `href`:

```
var path = location.pathname.substring(1);

$(this).parent().toggleClass("active", !hrefWindow || path === hrefWindow);
```

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try to rearrange my code using location.pathname .